# Error during installation of MySQL (Could not start service)

Tags: installation, crash, mysql, services

I am trying to install MySQL but I keep getting an error! I am using `mysql-5.5.11-winx64.msi` on Windows 7 x64.

The error message reads

> Could not start the service MySQL

Now the installer just hangs and then crashes.

When I try to start the service from an administrator command prompt with net start mysql, It just says

> The MySQL service cannot be started. System error 1067 has occurred. The process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: I have seen this problem you told me about. Unfortunately this error happens when you have already installed the service and you try to install it again. I can install MySQL, just not get the service to start properly.

Answer (score -1):

if you are experiencing this problem (error 0 cannot start the service mysql) try this solution:
first of all uninstall mysql from your computer and delete all files associated with mysql
go to the start menu of your computer and type regedit  (registry editor)
avigate the regedit to HKEY_LOCAL MACHINE/SYSTEM/CURRENT CONTROL SET/SERVICE
then delete anything to do with mysql
after that install your mysql again and it will install successfully